# How to parse json based on child node

Tags: json, jackson

```
{
"serialNumber":
{
    "number":"123443344334",
},
"receivedTime":"10/1/2015 6:06:22 PM",
"sessionId":"123456",
"dataPoint":
    [
        {"storedTime":"2015-10-01T11:45:23.000Z",
        "groupID":"123",
        "groupIndex":1,
        "vtmIndex":0,
        "dataType":"CONDITION",
        "data":
            {
            "conditionType":"TYPEA",
            "timeStamp":"2015-10-01T11:45:23.000Z"
            }
        },
        {"storedTime":"2015-10-01T11:45:23.000Z",
        "groupID":"123",
        "groupIndex":2,
        "vtmIndex":1,
        "dataType":"LOCATION",
        "data":
            {
            "latitude":22.23,
            "longitude":-43.12,
            }
        }
    ]
```

}

I am using Jackson, and am trying to figure out how to parse out this particular case... most of my other work is straightforward, but  need a second set of eyes on this one.

In the JSON above, I need to find the node whose child key "dataType" = "CONDITION", and then return the conditionType data element.  There are other data elements not shown here that also have a dataType of "CONDITION", but do not contain the conditionType field.

Answer (score 1):

With that data structure, is looks like you have no choice other than to iterate through the `dataPoint` array until you find the object with `dataType` of `CONDITION` (that is unless you absolutely know that this object would always be at some specific index position - like `0` in your example).  Once you have found that object, you need only look at it's `data`property to find the nested object with `conditionType` in it.